# Understanding evaluation of expressions containing '++' and '->' operators in C

Tags: c, operators, operator-precedence

Consider this example:

```
struct {
    int num;
} s, *ps;

s.num = 0;
ps = &s;
++ps->num;

printf("%d", s.num); /* Prints 1 */
```

It prints `1`.
So I understand that it is because according to operators precedence, `->` is higher than `++`, so the value `ps->num` (which is 0) is firstly fetched and then the `++` operator operates on it, so it increments it to 1.

```
struct {
    int num;
} s, *ps;

s.num = 0;
ps = &s;
ps++->num;

printf("%d", s.num); /* Prints 0 */
```

In this example I get `0` and I don't understand why; the explanation of the first example should be the same for this example. But it *seems* that this expression is evaluated as follows:
At first, the operator `++` operates, and it operates on `ps`, so it increments it to the next `struct`. Only then `->` operates and it does nothing because it just fetches the `num` field of the next `struct` and does nothing with it.
But it contradicts the precedence of operators, which says that `->` have higher precedence than `++`.

Can someone explain this behavior?

**Edit**:
After reading two answers which refer to a C++ precedence tables which indicate that a prefix `++`/`--` operators have lower precedence than `->`, I did some googling and came up with this [link](http://www.cs50.net/resources/cppreference.com/operator_precedence.html) that states that this rule applies also to C itself. It fits exactly and fully explains this behavior, but I must add that the table in this link contradicts a table in my own copy of K&R ANSI C. So if you have suggestions as to which source is correct I would like to know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The post-increment (`ps++`) and the pre-increment (`++ps`) have different associativity in C. The former associates left-to-right whereas the latter associates right-to-left. Check [this](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/operator_precedence) page out (though this is for C++, so the precedences may be misleading).

In your last example you are changing the pointer to one past the end of `&s`. You have not changed the value of the pointee. If you need to increment `num`, you need to bind the `++` to `num`.

**Detailed explanation:**

```
 ps++->num;
```

A (hypothetical) compiler on seeing this expression, may push the `ps` object to the stack followed by the `++` operator, the `->` operator and finally the object -- `num`. While evaluationg, where should the compiler start? It looks at the available operators i.e. `++` and `->`. Does it choose `ps++` or `ps`? Here precedence rules: since `->` has a higher precedence than `++`, it takes `->` to process with `num` as one operand and `ps` as the other operand. So, the value of the expression becomes `ps->num` i.e. 0 as you rightly observe. What happens to `ps` after the evaluation? Remember, there is another operator left on the stack? So, the compiler applies this to `ps` and it now points to one element past `&s`.

**Footnote:**

The ANSI/ISO C standard does not use a operator precedence grammar. Rather it uses what is known as a fully-factored grammar. This typically involves an exacting grammar definition dotted with a number of non-terminals like "primary-expression" and "shift-expression" and so on. This is hard to understand, but is easier for the language designer or the compiler vendor. Also, such a grammar is able to encode precedences easily. However, any fully-factored grammar is compatible with an operator-precedence grammar and this is what most books  (and websites) do (and also mess up at times).

Comment: The table at your link is for C++. According to K&R ANSI C, page 53, table 2-1, both prefix and postfix forms have the same precedence. This is what I based my question about. Had I known that they have different precedence I wouldn't have written what I wrote.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: Right, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: So - does it apply also to C? because if it did it would explain everything. It also seems to make sense. Maybe the table in K&R is dated?

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: You say that at a certain stage the compiler takes ++ to process with num as one operand, so according to that, we get the operation ++num (or num++, which one should that be?) which is undefined because we cannot refer to num outside it's context (which is the strcut).
Also, after the '++' is "wasted" on num how can it be used on ps?

Comment: Darn, that was a typo. Fixed it. It takes up `->`. Also, there are two things to note: 1) value of the expression and 2) side effects. No operators are wasted since they contribute differently -- in this context, `->` gives you the value and `++` the side-effect.

Comment: Thanks, now it is clearer. Sorry I make it hard for you, but who decides that the '++' operates on ps and not on the expression 'ps->num'? Example from arithmetic: if we have -2*3, then '*' has higher precedence than '-', so after the multiplication the '-' operates on the result which is 6 and not on '2'. Why wouldn't that rule apply here?

Comment: Unary '-' has a higher precedence than *. So, it really is (-2) * 3.

Answer (score 4):

Even if ++ had a higher priority, this wouldn't change the value -> operates on, as it's a post-increment. See this code that also has another example of this behaviour:

```
int b = 5;
int a = b++ * 3;
b = 5;
int c = (b++) * 3;

printf("%i, %i, %i\n", a, b, c); // Prints 15, 6, 15

struct {
  int num;
} s, *ps;

s.num = 35;
ps = &s;
printf("%p\n", ps); // Prints the pointer
printf("%i\n", ps++->num); // Prints 35
printf("%p\n", ps); // Prints the increased pointer

printf("%d\n", s.num); /* Prints 35 */
```

Comment: Excellent answer, in my opinion the best of those present now. BTW, from a maximum portability point of view, the ps pointer should be printed using format %p instead of %i.

Comment: The prints at line 5 are incorrect. It prints  "15, 7, 18". You also forgot one "%i" there. There should be three.

Comment: Sorry, edited the code and forget to reset b. Now I set b back to 5 to make it work as supposed.

Answer (score 3):

b = ++a; is equivalent to:

```
a += 1;
b = a;
```

b = a++; is equivalent to:

```
b = a;
a += 1;
```

So it's pretty clear why you don't get the result you look for. The thing you described would be equivalent to (++ps)->num.

Comment: Nearly equivalent. The technical difference, which I'm sure you knew, is that in the case of b = a++; or b = ++a; a is evaluated only once.

Answer (score 1):

"precedence" is basically a derived property; it follows from parsing rules.
++ps->num is parsed as ++(ps->num) /* () added for clarification of parsing rules */
whereas ps++->num can only be parsed as (ps++)->num.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that is because they have different priority, and within the same group, they have a specific associativity (eg. evaluation order)

Check [here](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm). The postfix operator has the same priority as the pointer resolution, but the prefix operator has a lower priority.

Answer (score 1):

ps++->num increments the pointer ps by 1, and then reads the data inside it. Since ps is just after s on the stack, I believe the pointer will most likely be pointing to itself, although this I'm not sure of, and is not important. basically The initial program was doing ++(ps->num) but without the brackets. To achieve the same thing but after you access the data, you would have to do (ps->num)++, or without the brackets: ps->num++.

And since ps is just a pointer, even though you changed its value, s still stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/) you can see that ++ as a prefix has lower priority than ->, but as a postfix it has the same priority as -> and it is evaluated from left to right, so ps++ is done first and then ->.

Edit: this is for C++, not C. So my answer isn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

Precedence is used to resolve ambiguous parsing. `++ps->num` could be parsed as `((++ps)->num)` or `(++(ps->num))`; the relative precedence of `++()` and `->` determines that the latter is the correct parsing.

For `ps++->num`, there is only one valid parsing: `((ps++)->num)`, so the precedence of the operators doesn't matter.